# Metal junction box cover

Tags: electrical

On a metal junction box cover, one side is stamped "Under Side".  Does that side go on the inside or outside of the box?

Answer (score 5):

"Under Side" goes inside the box.

Comment: Why?   It's a piece of sheet metal.   I agree with this answer, the side that has "under side" written on it goes inside the box..... but what is the difference?  I'll make this a new question.